# How can I get the items from a list of string that contain a determinate string value in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, list, arraylist

I have this list:

```
    Spain_Finance
    France_Sport
    Spain_Politics
    USA_Science
    USA_Finance
```

I use this code to check if the list contains a determinate value:

```
 Dim namecountry As String = "Spain"
    Dim listcontainscountry As Boolean = mylistofcountries.Any(Function(l) l.Contains(namecountry))
            If listcontainscountry = True Then
                  ' Here I need to get the elements from the list that contains Spain
            End If
```

So after doing this inside the if statement I need to get the elements from the list that contains Spain
The result will be this:

```
 Spain_Finance
 Spain_Politics
```

I looking for a simple code to do this, I can do a foreach and compare the name from country with the item list, but I want to know is there another way more simple, this is for learn, I appreciate your contribution, thanks

Comment: Why are you tagged to `c#`? with vb code?

Comment: because even if the answer is in c # I can translate it to vb.net

Comment: If your question is not specific to a language then don't tag it as specific to that language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Where` instead for `Any` so the code will be like the following:

```
Dim namecountry As String = "Spain"
Dim listcontainscountry = mylistofcountries.Where(Function(l) l.Contains(namecountry)).ToList()
```

Since the question is tagged to c# also, this [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zb520l) will help you, that is the code will be :

```
List<string> countryList = new List<string>() { "Spain_Finance", "France_Sport", "Spain_Politics", "USA_Science", "USA_Finance" };
string namecountry = "Spain";
List<string> SelectedCountries = countryList.Where(x => x.Contains(namecountry)).ToList();
if(SelectedCountries.Count>0) 
   Console.WriteLine("Selected Countries : {0}", String.Join(",",SelectedCountries));
else
   Console.WriteLine("No Matches ware found");
```

**update:** You can use `Select` followed by `Where` and `.SubString` the code will be like this

```
List<string> SelectedCountries = countryList.Where(x => x.Contains(namecountry))
                                                         .Select(x=>x.Substring(x.IndexOf("_")+1))
                                                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ,I have another question , it´s posible with the same code get a list of section names, for example: Finance, Politics?

Comment: Since OP also needs to know if there are items: `Dim containsCountries = listcontainscountry.Count > 0`. Trivial but on this way he doesn't need another `Any`-query.

Comment: @Esraa_92 : Your question is not clear enough, what will be the input and what will be the expected output?

Comment: @un-lucky : I ask if can I get with the same example the section names, from example in this case I get this result: Spain_Finance,Spain_Politics , but what If I want to get the sections of countries, like this: Finance, Politics

Comment: @Esraa_92 from what I can see the above code will work for that as well.

Comment: Similar to List<string> SelectedCountries, you want to extract just the sections? You can use split('_')[1] to get the section names

Comment: @Esraa_92 At that point it could be a Good Idea to use a class with properties like `Country` and `NewsType` instead of using one string to store both data items.

Comment: @un-lucky : thank you very much for your help and patient ;-)